# Ignoring required fields when updating item using a workflow

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow

Is it in any way possible for a workflow to ignore required fields in an item? I have a case where I would like a workflow to update items in another list under certain circumstances - however I cannot be 100% sure all required fields in the items are in fact not null (Since the requirement has been activated efter the item was created).

Answer (score 0):

It would seem if you enable content types and only in the content type configuration set fields as mandatory (As opposed to the setting under each column) the workflow does in fact ignore any requiremetns!